# How can I kill a forked process in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, fork

I am working on a game, so at one point I had to use `fork()`, the main thread runs opengl graphics, and the child thread runs the game logic.

Now I have a problem. At some point, the user may press the 'Exit' button inside the game, which is handled by the secondary thread. Also, at some point the user may click the X button to exit the game which is handled by the main (glut) thread. So here is my question: how can I kill the other running thread, and exit?

Right now, if I close the window, the second thread keeps running, and if the second thread finishes, the first one keeps running.

Handling the 'X' button could be done using the `atexit` function, but I haven't found a (safe) way of killing `glutMainLoop()`.

Comment: fork() creates a new process, not a new thread.

Comment: I see... what is the difference between `thread` and `process` then?

Comment: What, exactly, did you fork? I can't think of any reason that a fork would be desirable in a game (or really any desktop software). Windows doesn't even provide a similar function.

Comment: Well, apparently I made a confusion... I thought that fork() spawns a new thread, so this is why I used it, I confused threads and processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are actually calling `fork()` (instead of starting a new thread) then you are actually creating another running process.  When `fork()` is called, it returns a process-id to the parent process.  That can be passed to `kill()` to kill the process.  Under linux this looks like:

```
#include <signal.h>

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
   // you are in the child process
} else if (pid > 0) {
   // you are in the parent process
   ...
   // send a termination signal
   kill(pid, SIGTERM);
} else {
   // fork had an error which should be logged...
}
```

You need to choose what signal to send the process. SIGKILL (9) kills it hard for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please be precise about `thread` and `process` as they describe different subjects.

Since you use `fork()` you are actually dealing with processes. I recommend that you use `threads` instead, since it is much more memory efficient (since the program needs to be in memory only one time) and easier to handle. Of course you have to deal with critical sections yourself.

[Here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html) is a good example for working with threads.

If you insist on using processes and `fork()` you can still send signals and implement specific signal handlers. I'd also read some articles about IPC (Inter Process Communication) like http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html.